# How to create a <li> tag for each string from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

In JavaScript I have:

```
var cards = [
    'fa fa-diamond', 'fa fa-paper-plane-o', 'fa fa-anchor', 'fa fa-bolt', 
    'fa fa-cube', 'fa fa-anchor', 'fa fa-leaf', 'fa fa-bicycle', 
    'fa fa-diamond', 'fa fa-bomb', 'fa fa-leaf', 'fa fa-bomb', 'fa fa-bolt', 
    'fa fa-bicycle', 'fa fa-paper-plane-o', 'fa fa-cube'
];
```

And I want to create a `li` tag for each element in the ul that have the class name `deck`.

How can I achieve this?

```js
var cards = ['fa fa-diamond', 'fa fa-paper-plane-o', 'fa fa-anchor', 'fa fa-bolt', 'fa fa-cube', 'fa fa-anchor', 'fa fa-leaf', 'fa fa-bicycle', 'fa fa-diamond', 'fa fa-bomb', 'fa fa-leaf', 'fa fa-bomb', 'fa fa-bolt', 'fa fa-bicycle', 'fa fa-paper-plane-o', 'fa fa-cube'];
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Matching Game</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coda">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Matching Game</h1>
        </header>

        <section class="score-panel">
         <ul class="stars">
          <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
         </ul>

         <span class="moves">3</span> Moves

            <div class="restart">
          <i class="fa fa-repeat"></i>
         </div>
        </section>

        <ul class="deck">
          // HERE I WANT TO BE ADD a li tag for each string from var cards
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with a [foreach](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop.

```
cards.forEach(function(item) {
  document.getElementById('deck').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<li><i class="'+item+'"></i></li>');
});
```

here i used an ID instead of CSS class `deck`, which makes things easier!

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this, i have used simple for loop to iterate through all the array element and created dynamic li for each array item and then append it to deck.

```js
var cards = ['fa fa-diamond', 'fa fa-paper-plane-o', 'fa fa-anchor', 'fa fa-bolt', 'fa fa-cube', 'fa fa-anchor', 'fa fa-leaf', 'fa fa-bicycle', 'fa fa-diamond', 'fa fa-bomb', 'fa fa-leaf', 'fa fa-bomb', 'fa fa-bolt', 'fa fa-bicycle', 'fa fa-paper-plane-o', 'fa fa-cube'];

for(var i=0;i<cards.length;i++){
  var item = document.createElement("li");
  item.innerText = cards[i];
  document.getElementById("deck").append(item);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Matching Game</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coda">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Matching Game</h1>
        </header>

        <section class="score-panel">
         <ul class="stars">
          <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
         </ul>

         <span class="moves">3</span> Moves

            <div class="restart">
          <i class="fa fa-repeat"></i>
         </div>
        </section>

        <ul class="deck" id="deck">
<!-- // HERE I WANT TO BE ADD a li tag for each string from var cards -->
          
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please specify reason for down voting ?

Answer (score 0):

First I would add `id` to your `ul`:

```
<ul id="cardsList" class="deck">

</ul>
```

If you are not using jQuery, for plain JS you need something like this:

```
function fillInCardsList(cardsArr) {
  for (i = 0; i < cardsArr.length; i++) { 
    var liAsStr = '<li><i class="' +  cardsArr[i] + '"></i></li>';
    document.getElementById('cardsList').innerHTML += liAsStr;
  }
}
```

And then you can just call that function with your cards array as input:

```
fillInCardsList(cards);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Matching Game</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coda">    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var cards = ['fa fa-diamond', 'fa fa-paper-plane-o', 'fa fa-anchor', 'fa fa-bolt', 'fa fa-cube', 'fa fa-anchor', 'fa fa-leaf', 'fa fa-bicycle', 'fa fa-diamond', 'fa fa-bomb', 'fa fa-leaf', 'fa fa-bomb', 'fa fa-bolt', 'fa fa-bicycle', 'fa fa-paper-plane-o', 'fa fa-cube'];
        var str = '';

        cards.forEach(function(slide) {
          str += '<li><i class="'+ slide + '"></i></li>';
        }); 

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".deck").html(str);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Matching Game</h1>
        </header>

        <section class="score-panel">
            <ul class="stars">
                <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
            </ul>

            <span class="moves">3</span> Moves

            <div class="restart">
                <i class="fa fa-repeat"></i>
            </div>
        </section>

        <ul class="deck">
          // HERE I WANT TO BE ADD a li tag for each string from var cards
        </ul>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Map the array.

```
cards.map(x => document.querySelector('.deck').innerHTML += '<li><i class="'+x+'"></i></li>')
```

```js
let cards = ['fa fa-diamond', 'fa fa-paper-plane-o', 'fa fa-anchor', 'fa fa-bolt', 'fa fa-cube', 'fa fa-anchor', 'fa fa-leaf', 'fa fa-bicycle', 'fa fa-diamond', 'fa fa-bomb', 'fa fa-leaf', 'fa fa-bomb', 'fa fa-bolt', 'fa fa-bicycle', 'fa fa-paper-plane-o', 'fa fa-cube']

cards.map(x => document.querySelector('.deck').innerHTML += '<li><i class="'+x+'"></i></li>')
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class=deck></ul>
```

jQuery way:

```
$('.deck').html(cards.map(x=>'<li><i class="'+x+'"></i></li>'))
```